# Retrieve data from LocalDB in ASP.NET webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, localdb

I am using a simple webforms application to retrieve data to bind in a `GridView` control from `LocalDb\v11.0` locally. I have created `MyDb.sdf` and a table named info inside `App_Data` folder. I am getting the following error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

`Web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>    
    <add name="dbcs"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\MyDb.sdf;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>

    </div>
    </form>
```

**Back-end Code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string con = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(con))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from info", scon);
        scon.Open();

        GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataBind();

        scon.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure your `.sdf` file is in `app_data` then only you can access it else you have to use physical path. If your file is in `app_data` then you don't need a slash '\' just write `|DataDirectory|MyDb.sdf`

Comment: it is inside the aap_data folder. I have earlier mentioned it.

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment don't add a slash '\'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection string and code (using `SqlConnection`) is for a full-blown version of **SQL Server** (Express, Web, Standard, Enterprise), while the `.sdf` database file is for SQL Server **Compact Edition**.

Those two technologies are **NOT** compatible. You **cannot** attach a `.sdf` database file to your `(LocalDB)\v11.0` LocalDB instance - it needs to be a `.mdf` file.

Either use a **real** SQL Server (create a database in your SQL Server instance) and your current code - or then you need to switch to using `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeCommand` in your code

Comment: now this error is thrown back _Keyword not supported: 'attachdbfilename'._

Comment: done it by just using this ` connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MyDb.sdf;"`